# Img change while mouse move inside div containing it

Tags: 3d, mouse, perspective

I have prerender image sequance 3d scene, so i want to create something like in Flash, i want my picture changes then mouse move, if i moving left, image number goes up, if i moving right image number goes down, is it possible in Javascript and Jquery?

[This GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLw7.gif) best to illustrate what i mean